# Active voltage limit circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, zener, circuit-protection, precision

In my application there is a signal from 0-10V. The signal gets into 4 different OPAMPs with different gains which are supplied from +- 5V.

I would like to limit the input voltage to the OPAMP to 0-2.5V, so that when the signal reaches 2.5V, it will stay at 2.5V (a resistor divider is not an option).

I thought about a zener diode with a V<sub>Z</sub> of 2.5V. The problem with it is, that for a very low V<sub>Z</sub>, there could be a large tolerance at different temperatures and different currents.

If the V<sub>Z</sub> was 15V for example, it would be a good solution.

I hope to hear some ideas.

Accuracy is very important, so the solution must minimize the effect on the signal when it is in the permitted range.

Comment: Please show your schematic. Please use capital letters at the start of each sentence and for 'I'. Use 2 x <Enter> for new paragraph.

Comment: Please add some **numbers** to tell us what kind of accuracy you require. Also you need to describe the frequency range of the signal, again with actual numbers.

Comment: You can use op-amp based clipper and set the Vref to 2.5 V